# How to add search functionality to my application

Tags: c++, windows, indexing, full-text-search, information-retrieval

I am writing Windows application (with Borland C++ Builder), which stores large number of text files. I want users to be able to search these files very fast, so I need an indexing and search library. I do not use database, but my own file format for storing the documents (all are in a single file).

Are there such libraries for Windows? It should add/remove documents to the index per request and find documents similar to a Google query ("car house -payment").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CLucene](http://clucene.wiki.sourceforge.net/) is a C-Port of the lucene (java) library.
I have only used the original java version, but lucene is able to do what you are asking for.